# how do I create ADMIN VOB

Tags: clearcase

I am having a doubt in creating an admin vob.
Can anybody give an example in commandline? It is urgent.

---

update: thanks vonc for giving me the answer but i am using base clearcase and when i am creating tag to adminpvob its not treating as adminvob. Can you please explain me in detail with an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UCM, you need to create an Admin PVob in order for all UCM components to see each others.
If you are using base ClearCase, a simple Vob is enough (remove the '`-ucm`' option)
For instance, on a Unix ClearCase server:

```
$sudo /usr/bin/atria/bin/cleartool mkvob -tag /vobs/adminpvob -c "Global Admin UCM pvob" -ucm -public -password clearcase -host MY_SERVER -hpath /MY_SERVER/vobstore/adminpvob.vbs -gpath /net/MY_SERVER/vobstore/adminpvob.vbs /net/MY_SERVER/vobstore/adminpvob.vbs
```

Note: you need to declare the admin(p)vob tag in every ClearCase regions you are using.
Fort instance, on Windows:

```
ct mktag -vob -tag \adminpvob -public -password clearcase -host MY_SERVER -gpath \\MY_SERVER\vobstore\adminpvob.vbs \\MY_SERVER\vobstore\adminpvob.vbs
```

---

Once you have created a UCM PVob for instance, you can link it to your admin VOB:

```
ct mkhlink -c "Link to my pvob" AdminVOB vob:\mypvob vob:\adminpvob
Created hyperlink "AdminPVOB@107@\mypvob".
```

---

Note: you can chain several Admin Vobs, but I would recommend an Admin **P**Vob as the main one (with all the other linked to it). That way, even if you are not using UCM right now, any PVob you might create later can then just be linked to that global AdminPVob.
Simple Vobs can also be linked to it, enable ClearCase to share tag and branch names accross base ClearCase Vobs.

---

If you are **Base ClearCase only**:

```
$sudo /usr/bin/atria/bin/cleartool mkvob -tag /vobs/adminpvob -c "Global Admin vob" -public -password clearcase -host MY_SERVER -hpath /MY_SERVER/vobstore/adminvob.vbs -gpath /net/MY_SERVER/vobstore/adminvob.vbs /net/MY_SERVER/vobstore/adminvob.vbs

ct mkhlink -aquire -c "Link to my pvob" AdminVOB vob:\mypvob vob:\adminvob
Created hyperlink "AdminPVOB@107@\mypvob".
```

Note the '-acquire`' option, as specified in this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21124273).

> To avoid eclipsed types, you should create the AdminVOB hyperlink with the `-acquire` option.

You have the full process in the [help manual here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_typeadm_ls_hlink.htm).

> An administrative VOB hierarchy includes at least one administrative VOB and one or more VOBs that have an AdminVOB hyperlink to it or to another VOB that has an AdminVOB hyperlink to it.

[image]

Comment: (re your comment; the OP doesn't have the required rep to leave a comment, but I've merged the dup accounts)

Comment: Thank you Marc. Hopefully he will return and be able to ask further questions if this answer does not fully address his problem.