# ClearCase: how to list the attributes attached to a branch

Tags: clearcase

With the following, I can attach an attribute to a branch:

```
cleartool mkattr islocked \"true\" brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME
```

How can I verify the value of this attribute?

As advised by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), I specified the VOB name in my command:

First let ensure the attribute exist and has been registered:

```
$ ct mkattype -replace -nc -enum \"true\",\"false\" -default \"false\" islocked
Replaced definition of attribute type "islocked".
```

-

```
$ ct mkattr -replace islocked \"true\" brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME@\\myVOB
Created attribute "islocked" on "MY_BRANCH_NAME".
```

Then we can ask for the attribute's value:

```
$ ct desc -l brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME@\\myVOB
branch type "MY_BRANCH_NAME"
  created 2016-02-22T13:16:51Z by Nowox
  master replica: cpAdmin@\myVOB
  request for mastership: allowed for branch type
  request for mastership: allowed for all instances
  owner: user
  group: group
  scope: global
  constraint: one version per element
  Hyperlinks:
    GlobalDefinition@78418@\myVOB <- brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME@\myVOB
```

Unfortunately I don't see my attribute...

Same issue with this one:

```
$ ct desc -l -aattr islocked brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME@\\myVOB
MY_BRANCH_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cleartool describe`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-9&lang=en) can help:

```
cleartool desc -aattr myattribute brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME
```

[`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?lang=en) has also an option to display the value:

```
clearcase desc -fmt "%Sa" brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME
```

As [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) mentions in the comment, a `cleartool descr -l` can help ascertain if there is an attribute set and what its value is.
Compare that output with a `cleartool descr -l -local`  to see if the attribute differs, and if the object is a local instance of a global type.

If the attribute has been define [in an **AdminPVob**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057955/6309), check its type (global or local).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. The attribute is set because if I try to reapply it I get this error: `Error: Object already has an attribute of type "myattribute"`. When I try the latter option, I get no output.

Comment: @nowox Can you try with the fully qualified name: `cleartool mkattr -replace myattribute \"true\" brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME@\aPVob` and `cleartool desc -aattr myattribute brtype:MY_BRANCH_NAME@\aPVob`?

Comment: While you're at it, you may want to get cleartool desc -long and cleartool desc -long -local outputs. If this is a global brtype, you may see different results in the 2. You may also want to see if the attype is defined in the admin VOB, and whether it's local or global there.

Comment: @BrianCowan That is worth checking indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @nowox I have edited the answer with more checks suggested by Brian.

Comment: @VonC I edited my question, I still have some issues to get an attribute's value

Comment: @nowox did you create your attribute *type* first? (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattype.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-33&lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed similar issues on my side with the "cleartool desc" command. You can use the "cleartool dump" command in order to see the value of the attribute.

> cleartool dump -l brtype:YOUR-BRANCH@/YOUR-VOB